# Angular CLI set APP_BASE_HREF dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What I need to do is either set the `<base href="" />` tag dynamically that is located in the `index.html` OR set the `APP_BASE_HREF` dynamically that is in the `app.module.ts`

I am unsure how to set anything on the `index.html` as it's all static text it seems.

I have tried the following to set the `APP_BASE_HREF` but I keep getting the error below:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: url.replace is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: url.replace is not a function
    at _stripIndexHtml (common.js:282)
    at new Location (common.js:149)
    at _createClass (core.js:19829)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:19801)
    at initNgModule (core.js:19734)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:20461)
    at createNgModuleRef (core.js:20450)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:22281)
    at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (core.js:23009)
    at core.js:16622 TypeError: url.replace is not a function
    at _stripIndexHtml (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:25317:16)
    at new Location (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:25184:56)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:80131:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:80103:26)
    at initNgModule (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:80036:32)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:80763:9)
    at createNgModuleRef (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:80752:12)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:82583:12)
    at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:83311:25)
    at http://localhost:3577/vendor.js:76924:43
```

This is what I have tried:

```
export function startupServiceFactory(settingsService: SettingsService): Function {

    return async () => {
        const ombi = await settingsService.getOmbi().toPromise()

        const baseUrl = ombi.baseUrl.length > 0 ? ombi.baseUrl : "/";
        return baseUrl;
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
// snip
    ],
    declarations: [
// snip
    ],
    providers: [
        SettingsService,
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
            deps: [SettingsService],
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

as you can see in the above, I am attempting to call an API on the server which returns an object, then there is the `baseUrl` property that I want to set as the `APP_BASE_HREF`

I am aware this can be set during build time, but the website I have developed allows the user to set it themselves and the value is stored in the database (User's will install the application themselves).

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want this?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Mentions it at the bottom: `but the website I have developed allows the user to set it themselves and the value is stored in the database (User's will install the application themselves).`

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot use a factory provider returning a promise for `APP_BASE_HREF`([github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25932))

A possible workaround is to make the remote call to fetch the data before bootstraping the application, store the dynamic value somewhere (in `window` in the example below) and reuse it when providing `APP_BASE_HREF`

**main.ts**

```
fetch('https://yourbackendconfigserver.com')//Just an example of API call
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json =>{ 
  
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export function baseHRefFactory(): Function {
    return window['baseHref'];
}

@NgModule({
  imports:  //...
  declarations: //...
  providers:[
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useFactory: baseHRefFactory,
        }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbgh62)